# Plotting for next row after the slice

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting values of column `X` and `FT` according to column `CN` value in the following code

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, plt.plot(X[CN==1],FT[CN==1]), plt.plot(X[CN==36],FT[CN==36])`

and the data is given as

```
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+
| X     |  N  | CN | Vdiff | FT    |
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+ 
|   524 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 | 0.12. |
|   534 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 |0.134. |
|   525 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 |0.154. |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
|  5976 |  15 | 14 |   0.0 |3.54.  |
|  5913 |  15 | 14 |   0.1 |3.98.  |
|  5923 |   0 | 15 |   0.0 |3.87.  |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
| 33001 |   7 | 36 |   0.0 |7.36   |
| 33029 |   7 | 36 |   0.0 |8.99   |
| 33023 |   7 | 36 |   0.1 |12.45  |
| 33114 |   0 | 37 |   0.0 |14.33  |
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+
```

I am getting incomplete graphs so I need to use 1 next row in my plot. For example for the graph of `CN==36` as `plt.plot(X[CN==36],FT[CN==36])` I want to use first row of `CN==37` in my plot. Note that `CN` values are repetitive.

I have to plot multiple graphs in this way so a general code above graphs will be appreciated.
[image]
Addition on request in comment: Check at the end of the circular shape they are not touching their edges so circle is incomplete. for example for aqua & green color cycles. I want complete cycles so I need 1 or 2 additonal rows in data to plot.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. It's still not possible to tell whether the data is missing from the DataFrame, or if it's a grouping or plotting issue. A complete dataset, or a reproduceable random dataset that can be used to reproduce these graphs would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry dataset was incomplete without `CN` column now it with it at this link https://pern-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/shah_8113394_talmeez_pk/EcXFJAHGG99Bv-uO8Ofjdv0Bdv97o-NmSy57F-utPUFR2A?e=67SaU9